# How do you limit a border's width in css?

Tags: html, css

How do I limit the size of my footer's border? Currently it goes all the way across the whole page and I haven't for the life of me been able to figure out how to limit it to a certain size. Here's my html/css:

```css
.footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer p {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <footer>
    <p>&copy; 2015 Brian Funderburke</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you want to limit it? How much? As much as the text?

Comment: Probably a little wider than the text. I kind of want it to form the outline of the page width